# Dynamics 365 Ribbon Workbench Modal Dialog Opens in new Tab

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, crm-ribbon-workbench, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I have a custom button called "Sync Task" added to my Dynamics 365 app using the classic and new unified interface. The custom button is suppose to open a Web Resource HTML page in a Modal Dialog when clicked... but instead opens it in a new tab.

**Classic Interface Button**

[image]

**Unified Interface Button**

[image]

It opens the page in a new tab at the Web Resource location instead. Not sure what I could be doing wrong.

```
https://game.crm.dynamics.com//WebResources/SyncTaskLoadingPage
```

**My Dynamics Environment**

Dynamics 365, version 9.0

**My Ribbon Workbench Environment**

Ribbon Workbench 2016
Verion: 3.1.177.1
Author: Scott Durow

Button configuration

[image]

Action configuration, notice my Windows Mode is set to "ModalDialog".

[image]

Comment: Why //WebResources ??

Comment: that's how the URL is formatted in the Dynamics Solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328363.aspx#Remarks) says:

> Don’t use this action to open entity forms or web resources. Use the [`<JavaScriptFunction> (RibbonDiffXml)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334432.aspx) with a function that uses Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm or Xrm.Utility.openWebResource instead.

The latest v9 [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openwebresource):

```
Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource(webResourceName,windowOptions,data)
```

Comment: So instead of a URL action I should use a Script action to call this method?